# inserting value in meteor collection document

Tags: javascript, meteor

This code is trying to insert some value in a document when the method `storeUserinputs` is called, but I get error

> Error invoking Method 'storeUserInputs': Internal server error [500]

I went through it many times but could not find a problem. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
storeUserInputs: function (doc) {
    var activeTask = ActiveTaskCol.findOne({}, {fields: {action: 1}, sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 1}).action;
    console.log(doc);
    doc.forEach(function (obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        InputsCol.update({action: activeTask, name: obj[name]}, {$set: {value: obj[value]}});
   });
}
```

The above code console logged the following before throwing error

> [ { name: 'plate', value: 'x large' } ]
>   { name: 'plate', value: 'x large' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with way in which `obj`'s fields are accessed. It should be either `obj["name"]` or `obj.name` but not `obj[name]`.

Try this,

```
storeUserInputs: function (doc) {
    var activeTask = ActiveTaskCol.findOne({}, {fields: {action: 1}, sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 1}).action;
    console.log(doc);
    doc.forEach(function (obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        InputsCol.update({action: activeTask, name: obj.name}, {$set: { value: obj.value }});
        // or InputsCol.update({action: activeTask, name: obj["name"]}, {$set: { value: obj["value"] }});
    })
}
```

The error is because, you are using `name` and `value` variables which are not defined in the function.